# UL list with php while statement, how to do it right?

Tags: php, html, css

Here is the code ...

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subjects");
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "<li>" .  $fetch["menu_name"] . "</li>";   
        echo "<ul>";
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE subject_id = {$fetch["id"]}");
        while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo "<li>" .  $fetch["menu_name"] . "</li>";}
        echo "</ul>";
    }?>
```

the problem is that it gets one "subject" and the rest of the "pages" under it ...

I want it to get all subjects and all pages under it

I hope that you understood me
Thanks in advance
FarrisFahad

Comment: Why not do a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking for. However, you do have `<li></li>` on line 4 without a `<ul></ul>`. Maybe that's part of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong. But possibly because you are using the variable `$query` for both of the mysql queries. Try using a different variable, such as `$query1` or an other such useful name for the inner one.

Comment: That solves one of your problems (if you make sure you don't overwrite `$fetch` too). The other problem is that you're generating invalid markup: if you want nested lists, the whole nested list should be inside a `<li>`.

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing and overwriting your `$query` variable. After the inner `while` loop has looped through the result set, there's no more for the outer `while` to loop over.

Rename the second `$query` variable to something else.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to display, please include it.

the right way of displaying the data is:

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM subjects";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)):
?>
     <ul>
        <!-- field_name is the field name of the table you want to display-->
        <li><?php echo $row['field_name']?></li>
        <li><?php echo $row['field_name2']?></li>
        <li><?php echo $row['field_name3']?></li>
     </ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

also if you need two queries, the name of the other QUERY MUST be different from the other, so if you have the code above and you want to have another query, create a code like this:

```
<?php 
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE subject_id = '$row['id']'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)):
?>
    <!-- code for fetching of data here -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
```